# ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a general question. I want to develop a Web Application for business process modelling. The application was build using c# and WPF as  Desktop Application Software and now i would like to develope it as Web Application. what technology should i choose?

I've tried to find it myself but there are many different opinions about that topic. Is there any general rule or methodology which can help me decide?

Comment: See these posts on Programmer's : [Here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/95212/when-to-favor-webforms-over-mvc) and [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/100973/asp-net-vs-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: Unfortunately SO isn't suited to open ended or opinionated questions. If you get stuck somewhere and have a specific question, post to SO. Programmer's is a better bet for general 'advice'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite constructive. You need to talk to some Architect to understand your business and the requirements to fill up the gaps of choosing a technology. It is quite vague to answer your question whether to choose **ASP.NET webforms/MVC** or probably a different platform than .NET to suit your needs.

On a general answer, if you are planning to port your whole application developed on desktop using WPF, you can consider porting to Silverlight which *might* cut down your cost to 90% (probably), where you will able to reuse all codes you have written so far. But that's totally your call and your business needs.